# Mysql JOIN few table with multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have problems with mysql statement. I need join few table with multiple rows, and I want receive something like:

- 1 row from ad
- 4 rows from ad_city (ON ad.id = ad_city.adId)
- 4 rows from ad_entry (ON ad.id = ad_entry.adId)
- 4 rows from ad_object (ON ad.id = ad_object.adId)

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.date,
    a.text,
    u.id AS "userId",
    u.name AS "userName",
    u.surname AS "userSurname",
    te.id AS "entryId",
    tet.name AS "entryType",
    ter.name AS "entryRegion",
    to.id AS "objectId",
    tot.name AS "objectType",
    tor.name AS "objectRegion",
    c.id AS "cityId",
    c.name AS "city",
    ac.acId,
    ac.acAdId,
    ac.acCityId,
    ac.acCity,
    ae.aeId,
    ae.aeAdId,
    ae.aeEntryId,
    ae.aeEntryType,
    ae.aeEntryRegion,
    ao.aoId,
    ao.aoAdId,
    ao.aoObjectId,
    ao.aoObjectType,
    ao.aoObjectRegion,
FROM
    `ad` AS `a`
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            ac.id AS "acId",
            ac.ad_id AS "acAdId",
            c.id AS "acCityId",
            c.name AS "acCity",
        FROM
            `ad_city` AS `ac`
            LEFT JOIN `main_city` AS `c` ON ac.main_city_id = c.id
    ) AS `ac` ON ac.acAdId = a.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            ae.id AS "aeId",
            ae.ad_id AS "aeAdId",
            to.id AS "aeEntryId",
            tot.name AS "aeEntryType",
            tor.name AS "aeEntryRegion",
        FROM
            `ad_entry` AS `ae`
            LEFT JOIN `some_object` AS `to` ON ae.some_object_id = to.id
            LEFT JOIN `some_type` AS `tot` ON to.some_type_id = tot.id
            LEFT JOIN `some_region` AS `tor` ON to.some_region_id = tor.id
    ) AS `ae` ON ae.aeAdId = a.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            ao.id AS "aoId",
            ao.ad_id AS "aoAdId",
            to.id AS "aoObjectId",
            tot.name AS "aoObjectType",
            tor.name AS "aoObjectRegion",
        FROM
            `ad_object` AS `ao`
            LEFT JOIN `some_object` AS `to` ON ao.some_object_id = to.id
            LEFT JOIN `some_type` AS `tot` ON to.some_type_id = tot.id
            LEFT JOIN `some_region` AS `tor` ON to.some_region_id = tor.id
    ) AS `ao` ON ao.aoAdId = a.id
    LEFT JOIN `some_object` AS `to` ON a.some_object_id = to.id
    LEFT JOIN `some_type` AS `tot` ON to.some_type_id = tot.id
    LEFT JOIN `some_region` AS `tor` ON to.some_region_id = tor.id
    LEFT JOIN `some_object` AS `te` ON a.some_entry_id = te.id
    LEFT JOIN `some_type` AS `tet` ON te.some_type_id = tet.id
    LEFT JOIN `some_region` AS `ter` ON te.some_region_id = ter.id
    LEFT JOIN `main_city` AS `c` ON a.main_city_id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN `user` AS `u` ON a.user_id = u.id
WHERE
    a.id = 1 -- example
    AND a.user_id = 2 -- example
ORDER BY
    a.date DESC
```

Is is possible receive this data in one statement?

I received 64 rows which I have to map this to the format which I need. In my statement I joined col adId, from ad_city, ad_entry, ad_object because I need this variables to create correct server received. Is is possible receive smaller data from DB?

DB to Server is sending 64 rows data. It is big packet. On server I have to do many loops and conditions to format data.

Or should I send 4 independent request to DB?

Server response:

```
{
    id: //
    date: //
    text: //
    user: {
        //
    },
    city: //
    entry: //
    object: //
    arrCity: [
        //
    ],
    arrEntry: [
        //
    ],
    arrObject: [
        //
    ]
}
```

I am Node.js Developer and I rarely use mysql (I am working on real time data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it sounds like, you are trying to get a response that has multiple row formats within it (Getting one row from ad, getting 4 rows from ad_city etc.)

A MySQL query will only ever return a single table, so all rows will have the same columns. If you need data from different tables about different data, and do not want to use a JOIN to combine data, then you will need to make multiple queries.